# How can I get this to be manifold?

Tags: vertices

I'm at my wits end with this file, it seems every edit I try to make to fix this file results in even more non-manifold edges, digging myself in deeper. Using online repair sites don't work and the "Make Manifold" 3-D cleanup option just removes the walls between the objects. Can anyone help? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Looking at the file, I agree, this *is* a mess.  This is enough of a mess that I would start over from scratch.  I'm not sure what techniques you're using to generate geometry like this, but I'd recommend thinking about what those techniques are doing, and checking for non-manifold geometry often throughout modelling until you get the hang of it.  Use "select non manifold" operation in Blender to find it without any addons or 3rd party tools.  I'd also recommend fewer use of ngons for now-- use quads or triangles for now.